# Passar variável pelo ConverterParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
Visibility = "{Binding TipoDestinatario, Converter={StaticResource conversorTipoDestinatario}, ConverterParameter=}.
```

Precisaria passar uma variável booleana pelo `ConverterParameter=`, alguém saberia como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SeuChapeu, até aqui não consegui usar Binding para o ConverterParameter. Como você precisa passar uma variável, uma sugestão viável é usar o MultiBinding:

### XAML

```
<Label x:Name="situacaoPedidoLabel" Width="200" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Situação">
    <Label.Visibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource VisibilidadePedidoConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding Path="Pedido.Situacao" />
                <Binding Path="PodeFecharPedido" />
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Visibility>
</Label>
```

### Converter

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace CSharp2.Capitulo10.Wpf.Produtos.Converters
{
    public class VisibilidadePedidoConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                var podeVisualizar = (System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]) == 1) && System.Convert.ToBoolean(values[1]);

                return podeVisualizar ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            }
            catch 
            {
                return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Not implemented");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: como faço pra passar um valor que vem de um método que está no presenter?

Comment: Bem, uma alternativa é o método ser void e manipular diretamente o valor que você precisa:
public void Initialize() 
{
    Contact = LoadContactFromDatabase();
}

public Contact Contact { get; set; }